# Handle android permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have simple question. my first activity check phone permission, when the permission is deny (don't ask again) I show dialog and go to app settings for change permission. how to handle permission change my resumed activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the permission check within the `onResume()` each time your activity is recreated it'll check the permission again.

Comment: When check permission onResume method infinite loop because dialog open activity onResume called multiple times